# can't use sjPlot in R

Tags: r, sjplot

I followed the instructions on https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/ to install the package but despite downloading and installing all the packages, I can't use them because I keep getting the error message
`could not find function "sjP.lmer"`

does anyone know where this is coming from? I'd be happy to provide more details but I don't even know where to look for them...

Comment: The error means the package is not loaded. You are either not loading it using `library` or it failed to install properly. It is not possible to comment further without additional information, e.g. stack trace of the install process, OS, R version...

Comment: The functions `sjp.lmer()`, `sjp.glmer()` etc. were deprecated for a long time and removed in the latest update, which appeared just a few days ago on CRAN. So this may be another reason for your error. Depending on your package-version, you should use `plot_model()` now.

Comment: That seems to work better @Daniel, thank you!